# How can I see the duration of a phone call on Google Voice?

Tags: android-12, google-voice, google-pixel-6

How can I see the duration of a phone call on Google Voice? Sometimes I don't see the duration.

Example:

[image]

Sometimes I do see the call duration though:

[image: we]

I use Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.